# How to explore running wpf applications?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a tool to explore 3rd party wpf app such as navigate visual tree, look at styles and templates, change some parameters at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) might help out there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about changing things at runtime but [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is definitely an awesome tool for looking at a WPF application's visual tree.